# Is $\liminf f(x)$ always unique?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, solution-verification, limsup-and-liminf

Searching for the question doesn't seem to give any relevant answers on stack exchange or on google. I know that $\liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty} f(x_n)$ is always unique, but I haven't seen a proof for it. Here is my attempt:

Assume $l, l'$ are two valid values of $\liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty} f(x_n)$ for some real valued function $f$ and a sequence $x_n$ that converges to $x_0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$. Without loss of generality, assume that $l'=l+\eta$ for some $\eta > 0$. From the definition of $\liminf$, we have that for any fixed $\epsilon> 0$, there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that for all $x \in N_\delta(x_0)$: $f(x) > l - \epsilon$ and $f(x) > l' - \epsilon$. Adding these inequalities together and substituting the value of $l'$:

$$f(x) > l - \epsilon + \eta / 2$$

Let $\epsilon = \eta / 2$ so that the above inequality is: $f(x) > l$. But this is a contradiction since the $\liminf$ is the greatest lower bound: for some $x \in N_\delta (x_0)$ we have that $f(x) < l + \eta / 2$ and $\eta$ can be made arbitrarily small.

Is this last point correct? Is the result truly a contradiction or am I missing a step?

Comment: Since I'm still familiarizing myself with the concept, please excuse my potential ignorance, but I believe it follows directly from the fact that limits of sequences are unique, hence why there wouldn't be a proof for it. Define the sequence $\left(\inf\limits_{i\geq n} x_i\right)_{n=m}^{\infty}$. Assuming this sequence converges, the limit of the sequence is unique, hence $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\inf x_n$ is unique.

Comment: That's a good point. I don't think we need the assumption on whether it converges. Taking your idea: $\liminf x_n = \sup_m \inf{n\geq m} x_n$. The infimum is unique for each $m$ and so is the supremum.

Comment: What's your definition? Suprema and infima are unique, and the limits superior and inferior are usually defined in terms of those.

Comment: For *existence* of $\liminf$, we need to allow possible values $+\infty$ and $-\infty$.  Then your reduction $l'=l+\eta$ is a problem.

Comment: Note $(x_n)$ needn't be convergent for $\liminf f(x_n)$ to exist, so this assumption is stronger than necessary.

Comment: If you consider a sequence (assumed real sequence) being actually _a function_ $x:\mahtbb N\to\mathbb R$, then your $f(x_n)$ is simply a composition $(f\circ x)(n).$ Name the composed function: $g = f\circ x$ and your question becomes: is $\liminf$ of an arbitrary sequence $g_n = g(n)$ always unique?

Answer (score 1):

I am giving you a demonstration , I hope it helps you.

Suppose $f(x_n)$ has at least two limits $M,L$ such that $L<M$. Considering $\epsilon = \frac{M-L}{2}$, It is well defined because $\epsilon > 0 $.As L is a Limit of $f(x_n)$ exists $N_1$ such that:

$$\forall n \geq N_1 , L - \epsilon < f(x_n) < L +\epsilon.$$

And As M is a Limit of $f(x_n)$ exists $N_2$ such that:

$$\forall n \geq N_2 , M - \epsilon < f(x_n) < M +\epsilon.$$

Defining $N = \max{(N_1,N_2)}$ therefore $f(x_N)$ verify both inequalities, in particular :

$$M - \epsilon < f(x_N) < L +\epsilon.$$

As $\epsilon = \frac{M-L}{2} \Rightarrow M-\epsilon = \frac {M+L}{2}$ and $L+\epsilon = \frac{M+L}{2}$, finally:

$$ \frac{M+L}{2}$ < f(x_N)< \frac{M+L}{2}$$.

In conclusion as it is a contradicction $f(x_n) $could only have one limit.